# Tracking celestial objects using GPS location

Tags: android, ios, gps

I am trying to create a little app that mimics several that are out there. I have not downloaded any of the APK's to try and de-compile them yet. I will try that if this question does not get any answers.

So, I'd like to create a simple app to start that will just find the sun. Should be pretty easy, right? I am not sure if there is a pre-built API that I can use or if there are static calculations I can use, or how this is being done.

I'm guessing the GPS on a device would provide location and time. This should be the only thing needed from the device, and the rest can be calculated then displayed to the user.

I am doing this to learn some things about app creation, dynamic locations, and just something fun to do.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks fellow Stackers!

Comment: Look into Google's [Sky Map](https://code.google.com/p/stardroid/). Its open source. Better to go through open source than violate copyright laws by decompiling.

Comment: @RaghavSood - Thanks for the SkyMap Link - Also: Decompiling is not violating and copyright laws. It is when you use that code that you violate laws. However, Decompiling an APK to see if they are using a public API, or if they are using celestial mechanics algorithms is not illegal what so ever.

Comment: "Decompiling is not violating and copyright laws. It is when you use that code that you violate laws." -- please consult with qualified legal counsel regarding your claims, as your statement is not true in all jurisdictions. In the US, for example, you may be liable under the anti-circumvention clause of the DMCA, if the app uses any form of copy protection.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thought: Location and time are not enough if you're trying to *point* to the sun.

Besides the **position** of the device (its coordinates) at a given time, you'll also need its **orientation**, which can be computed using [SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html).